# Visual Studio 2013 + Typescript + Web Essentials = no auto closing braces

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, web-essentials

I've installed Web Essentials for VS 2013 Update 2 and I am not getting auto closing braces (and auto closing parentheses) on Typescript files.

From what I read on some forums ([link to forum](http://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general/suggestions/3782308-automatically-add-line-between-braces-in-typescrip)), it does exist and should be available. Is there a way to enable it?

Thanks!

ps: for JS files everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `Tools->Options->Text Editor->TypeScript->Automatic brace completion` option (which controls this feature) is disabled.

You can manually enable this option by adding the following DWORD registry value (set it to 1):

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\Languages\Language Services\TypeScript\ShowBraceCompletion
```

Once it's enabled (restart VS to see the change), you can go into the options and check it off. Hopefully that's enough to make it start working (if there really is already support for brace completion in TypeScript). **Update**: It seems this still doesn't enable brace completion -- it looks like the TypeScript language service itself simply doesn't support it (in VS2013 Update 2 anyway, which is what I tried it on -- but note that I don't have WebEssentials installed).

Note that this is more of a hack than a proper fix, since Visual Studio can reconstruct the `12.0_Config` key any time it likes (this happens when you install/uninstall/enable/disable an extension, for example). A more permanent patch is to create a small Visual Studio extension with a [.pkgdef file that sets that registry value](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d649a9e5-f53d-49e4-a0fb-953b261bb62e/vs2013-how-is-the-automatic-brace-completion-option-enabled-on-the-settings-page-for-a-custom?forum=vsx) (when the `12.0_Config` key is reconstructed, it looks at all the .pkgdefs to see what it should put there).

Comment: Yes, I just tried that "hack", the option was enabled on VS Options but it didn't work on the code. That is very sad, it would be much better to code with that feature. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user: Ah well, sorry it didn't work. Was worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension here that will add brackets automatically: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e33cb22-d4ac-4f5a-902f-aff5177cc94d